# Server Time is *WAY* Off

Tags: fedora, ntpd, ntpdate

The time on my server is about 19 hours behind and I cannot for the life of me figure out how to synchronize it. I did follow the steps [here](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/printthread.php?t=121018), and this is the output:

```
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# /sbin/service ntpd stop
Shutting down ntpd:                                        [  OK  ]
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# /usr/sbin/ntpdate 0.pool.ntp.org
25 Oct 08:42:32 ntpdate[22173]: adjust time server 199.4.29.166 offset 0.034126 sec
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 01:43:18 PM MST  -0.344112 seconds
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# /usr/sbin/ntpdate nist1-ny.ustiming.org
25 Oct 08:44:41 ntpdate[22180]: adjust time server 64.90.182.55 offset -0.002749 sec
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 01:45:24 PM MST  -0.593604 seconds
```

In response to suggestions in the comments:

```
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# ntpdate -u tick.usno.navy.mil
25 Oct 09:00:40 ntpdate[22294]: adjust time server 192.5.41.40 offset 0.111328 sec

[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 02:00:46 PM MST  -0.140884 seconds
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# date
Tue Oct 25 09:01:10 MST 2011

[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# TZ=Z date
Tue Oct 25 16:01:20  2011
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]#
```

Yet more...

```
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 zoneinfo]# ln -s /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York /etc/localtime
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 zoneinfo]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 05:17:24 PM EDT  -0.270220 seconds

[root@ip-72-167-39-231 zoneinfo]# export TZ=America/New_York
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 zoneinfo]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 05:21:42 PM EDT  -0.656424 seconds
```

I wouldn't care, but email that is sent right now is showing up on clients as if it was sent yesterday afternoon...

Comment: Is timezone correct?

Comment: Quanta, the time zone on the server is MST, but it's not correct even for that. It is 9.55am MST currently, but it's showing as 1:55pm yesterday.

Comment: Is this a VM?  Also, that looks like you're 19 hours behind (8AM to 1PM the previous day) not 28.  Does `date` return the same thing as [hw]`clock`?  (as an aside, you don't need to shut down ntpd if you use `-u` with `ntpdate`)

Comment: What happens if you run `TZ=Z date`?

Comment: Responses to these suggestions have been updated and edited above. I am not sure what "VM" stands for. It is a dedicated server, not virtual.

Comment: It looks like "date" is accurate, but not "clock".

Comment: @TomThorogood Fix the time on your VM host, then!

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: @TomThorogood Ok, let's back up a bit - what is this system?  Physical server?  Virtual machine?  Hosted by someone somewhere?

Comment: @Shane It doesn't matter, it's the Time Zone settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
ntpdate -u pool.ntp.org
hwclock --adjust
hwclock --systohc
```

This will update your time settings from pool.ntp.org, adjust your hwclock for systematic drift, and then sync your hardware clock to your system clock. [man page for hwclock](http://linuxcommand.org/man_pages/hwclock8.html)

**If you run these commands on a VM host this may adversely affect all of the VM guests and their ability to display the correct time. Plan accordingly.**

Although I don't know if the hwclock -s will do anything on the VM guest ... I am going to guess no.

Comment: That did it! I am the only user on this server; this won't affect anyone else.

Comment: Great! Glad to help. :)

Comment: Is `hwclock` a 'fire and forget' command, or does it need to be invoked every time `ntpdate` is run?

Comment: Ah, I see that [`ntpd` can be configured to sync the hwclock](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/document?cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en&tmp_geoLoc=true&docname=c03138326).

Answer (score 4):

On any *normal* *nix system, `ntpdate -u tick.usno.navy.mil` should set the clock correctly.

If your timezone settings are off, the `date` command will still return the wrong "local time".

Comment: 25 Oct 09:00:40 ntpdate[22294]: adjust time server 192.5.41.40 offset 0.111328 sec
[root@ip-72-167-39-231 ~]# clock
Mon 24 Oct 2011 02:00:46 PM MST  -0.140884 seconds

Comment: Your timezone settings are off, but the server has the correct UTC time. Running `date -u` should confirm this. It should return "Tue Oct 25 16:03:14 UTC 2011" as of a few seconds ago.

Comment: Okay. But I still do not know how to update it.

Comment: date -u returns the correct time; how do I update "clock" so that it's accurate?

Comment: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-linux-unix-change-setup-timezone-tz-variable/ basically `ln /usr/share/zoneinfo/[TZ_Code] /etc/localtime` (Note: /etc/localtime probably already exists and is linked to something wrong).

Comment: That did not solve the issue, either. Tried changing it to NY (so it would be the same time zone as me). Output is above.

Comment: @ChrisS Why not pool.ntp.org? Just curious ...

Comment: @JosephKern They're quite reliable, but the Navy is more; for one off syncs I commonly use tick. For any recurring polling I would always recommend using several of the pool servers.